# Sub to add controls works when called from one sub but the other

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am getting an error that I just can't figure out. I wrote a sub that opens a form in Design view, deletes all of the dynamic controls, then adds the requested number.

The sub gets called in two different ways. The user opening the form (via a Main Menu form) to fill out a new form (so the dynamic controls are deleted then recreated) **OR** after the form is created, the user can click a button on the form to add more rows of controls. Both the Main Menu and button form call the same sub, **BUT** when the button is clicked the code gets stuck and error 29054 '**Microsoft Access can't add, rename, or delete the control(s) you requested.**' is thrown. The button to debug is deactivated so I can't see what line is actually getting stuck, but when I step through the code this is the last line before the error pops up (the last indent block in the context below):

```vb
    With Application.CreateControl("BOM5", acComboBox, acDetail, frm.Controls("Tabs").Pages(PageNum).Name, , ChangeTypeLeft, LastControlTop, ChangeTypeWidth, ControlHeight)
```

The rest of the code is as follows.

```vb
    DoCmd.OpenForm "BOM5", acDesign
    Set frm = Application.Forms("BOM5")

    ' Cycle through controls and set LastControlTop based on the last dynamic control, if any
    For i = 0 To frm.Controls.Count - 1
        Set ctl = frm.Controls(i)
        Debug.Print ctl.Name
        If ctl.Tag Like DYNAMIC_TAG & "*" Then
            If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
                LastControlTop = ctl.Top + ControlHeight + ControlPadding
                FormRowCount = FormRowCount + 1
            End If
        Else
            FormRowCount = (FormRowCount / 6) + 1      ' Convert number of fields to number of rows then add one to start new batch of controls

            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    PageNum = frm.Controls("Tabs").Pages.Count - 1      ' .Pages has an index of 0. Getting PageNum to follow suit with the -1

    ' Add controls for inputting parts
    For FormRowCount = FormRowCount To NewControlCount
        With Application.CreateControl("BOM5", acComboBox, acDetail, frm.Controls("Tabs").Pages(PageNum).Name, , ChangeTypeLeft, LastControlTop, ChangeTypeWidth, ControlHeight)
            .Name = "ChangeType" & FormRowCount
            .Tag = DYNAMIC_TAG
            .RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
            .RowSource = "ChangeType"
        End With
```

The last for loop has 5 other With Application.CreatControl statements, but I just showed the first one. The other 5 are similar except text boxes instead of combo.

I've had this error before, but I think I resolved it by moving the DoCmd.OpenForm statement to a different part of the code (like out of an if statement or for loop or somewhere that wasn't letting it get called) but I don't think that will resolve it. Besides, the first for loop iterates correctly since I see it grabbing the control height of the last dynamic control.

Comment: In your code I see no attempts to delete existing controls. Are you sure that control that should be created did not exist when you run your Sub with button?

Comment: Woops, forgot to include that bit. The deletion is in a separate sub. Originally it was in the same sub but split it when I added the button so I wouldn't delete the controls I was suppose to be adding onto. I guess I tend to forget that I split the operations.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. A form or report can only hold a certain amount of controls, deleted or not, so - eventually - it will not accept more controls. At that point, you must recreate the form from scratch.

So, don't delete the controls. Create those you may need and, at any time, hide those not needed and rename the rest if necessary.

Comment: Except I've been able to. I get that access has a max of 255 controls, but since my controls have the same name, I assume, I can get around this. I've created, deleted, and recreated 160 controls several times over the course of a few days to test this limitation.

Comment: That all said, in this particular case, I can create 10 controls when opening from the main menu. However, if I create 5 controls then try to add 5 more later I get the error. So I don't think my issue is this limitation.

Comment: It is far more than 255, but can't recall the figure. In any case, to delete and recreate  is a dead end with a full stop.

Comment: @Gustav is absolutelly right !!! Try to save your form to file `SaveAsText acForm ,"FormName","c:\tempFormFile"` And look at line with `ItemSuffix =`. This is internal access counter wich is never decremented. BUT you can do such workaround: 1. save form `SaveAsText acForm ,"FormName","c:\tempFormFile"` 2. open file and 2.1. delete line `Checksum = ....`  2.2. set `ItemSuffix =` to any save value 2.3. save file 3. load it back to access `LoadFromText acForm ,"FormName","c:\tempFormFile"` .

Comment: It looks like at Access2010 this limitation is removed. And Access gives name with negative numbers like `Label-32767`